# Javascript Date.getTimezoneOffset() not working in Node-red

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, timezone, node-red, timezone-offset

I have Node-red running on a Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspbian Stretch.
This output confirms that the CET timezone is actually set:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ timedatectl
      Local time: Tue 2019-12-10 22:29:51 CET
  Universal time: Tue 2019-12-10 21:29:51 UTC
        RTC time: n/a
       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CET, +0100)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

I am trying to calculate the timezone-offset between my current timezone (CET) and the GMT time.
To this end I am using the following line in the function node of node-red:

```
msg.payload = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

But instead of an expected offset of one hour (60 minutes), it returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/timezone-settings/1176) and [this](https://techible.net/setting-the-timezone-in-nodered/), one needs to set the time zone explicitly for Node-Red in the `settings.js` file (located in `$home/.node-red`):

```
process.env.TZ = "Europe/Berlin";
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I am just copying from the linked references.  I don't use node-red, so please tell me if this worked or not.  Thanks.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. Works like a charm. Now I can remove my ugly workarounds.